# Facebook and Twitter icons don't work, others do

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Font Awesome is installed, and most icons work. Facebook and Twitter icons, however, do not.

I have tried changing the fa class to fab, and vice versa: neither work.

Here is the code. The top icon renders correctly:

```
<a href="mailto:info@site.org">info@site.org</a> <i class="fas fa-envelope" style="margin-left: 5px"></i><br />
<a href="https://twitter.com/site">@site</a> <i class="fab fa-twitter" style="margin-left: 5px"></i><br />
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/site/">site</a> <i class="fa fa-facebook" style="margin-left: 5px"></i>
```

Any suggestions on how to get the social icons working is greatly appreciated!

**Fix**: This was just a case of not having updated FontAwesome to the latest version, so the icon references were broken. Easy mistake! Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: I saw the site, the icons on bottom right are perfectly. Okay.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed the problem and posted an answer here explaining how, which a moderator promptly deleted without explanation 

Comment: you can post again. or edit this question and include the **Fix**

Answer (score 2):

Icons work properly. Probably you made an error somewhere.

```html
<i class="fab fa-3x fa-facebook"></i>
<i class="fab fa-3x fa-facebook-f"></i>
<i class="fab fa-3x fa-facebook-square"></i>
<i class="fab fa-3x fa-twitter"></i>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/js/all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: They don't work properly on my site because of an error I have made, but cannot identify. That's why I posted here..?